# I'n JSON how to display 10000 as 10 K .{data;10000}

Tags: json, jsonata

I'n JSON how to display 10000 as 10 K .{data;10000}

I'n JSON how to display 10000 as 10 K .{data;10000} how to display as unit if 1000 means 1k 10000 means 10 k

Comment: Would you be able to provide more context on your question? Is it about JSONata language as one of your tags indicates? If so, what are the intended input and the output? Please provide valid JSON examples.

Comment: Test{value:10000,name :abc} i tried as test.$formatNumber.{value,'#,###'} it's displayed as 10,000 but I want to display as 10K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `$formatNumber` supports it out of the box (check the docs for more info: https://docs.jsonata.org/numeric-functions#formatnumber)

But if you only ever display thousands there - you can divide the number by 1000 yourself and then format it:

```
$formatNumber(value / 1000, "#K")
```

On the playground: https://stedi.link/mkATNe7